# getting the value of an attribute from another attributes value in xslt/xpath

Tags: xslt, xpath, attributes

I need to read the path to an image from an attribute. The path to the element that contains this attribute is only referenced by another attribute of another element. That is, I have an ID in one element that refers to another ID in whose element the attribute with my desired path is located. I want to use the path as an attribute in an html-tag.

xml source

```
<root>
     <a lot of nodes>
       <relation id="path_1" path="path/to/image1">
       <relation id="path_2" path="path/to/image2">
       ...
     <more nodes>
       <reference path="path_1">
       <reference path="path_2>
       ...
</root>
```

desired output (xslt snippet, something like this)

```
<xsl:template match="path/to/reference">
  <img src="{@path}>
  <xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

desired output (html snippet)

```
<img src="path/to/image1>
...
<img src="path/to/image2>
```

How can I use the ID from element "reference" to read the value of the ID from element "relation"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using an `xsl:key` here (This must be placed in your stylesheet as a direct child of `xsl:stylesheet`):

```
<xsl:key name="relations" match="relation" use="@id" />
```

Then, in your template matching `reference`, you can do this

```
<xsl:template match="reference">
   <img src="{key('relations', @path)/@path}" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This works, thx. So easy :). Since I think it is the simpler solution compared to the first answer, I choose this one. The other one may work, but I didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

A template that can satisfy your needs could be

```
<xsl:template match="relation[@id = ../reference/@path]">
  <img src="{@path}">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </img>
</xsl:template>
```

Its output is:

```
<img src="path/to/image1"/>
<img src="path/to/image2"/>
```

---

The other way round it is:

```
<xsl:template match="reference[@path = ../relation/@id]">
  <img src="{../relation/@path}">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </img>
</xsl:template>
```

which yields the same output.